# Replace string in firefox current page

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, firefox

i want to replace string ("123" with "111") in the firefox current page html.

explanation:

i'm opening firefox, and then i'm navigating to:

```
www.site.com/print.php?string=123
```

i'm waiting until the document is fully loaded

the page html:

```
<html>
<body>
123
</body>
</html>
```

i'm replacing the string "123" with "111".

The code is should look like:

```
        openff("http://www.site.com/print.php?string=123") 'open url
again:
        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox") 'wait until page is fully loaded
            If p.MainWindowTitle = "123 page title" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                Application.DoEvents()
                GoTo again
            End If
        Next
        replaceInFFcurrentDocHtml("123", "111") 'Replace the string!!!
```

the function `replaceInFFcurrentDocHtml()` is not really exist.

there is a function that can `replace` string in the firefox current page html?

Or function that `get` the current html from `firefox`?

(i tried to get the html by spy++ using handle and windows, but this way not working)

Comment: Why not make a browser extension?

Answer (score 0):

This isnt exactly "hacking into firefox" per se, but it might work.

Use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and download the contents of the site as a String, call replace on that String with whatever you might really need and write the result to a temporary html file. Lastly, either specifically invoke firefox to open said html file or ask the OS to resolve which application should open it using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

I believe Firefox (And for security reasons, no browser should) allows external modifications to the DOM. This is the only approach that is valid without cooking up some complex modifications over Firefox' code.

Also, a nice tip: Dont use GoTo, [its a bad idea](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF).

Answer (score 0):

You could write and Firefox extension to modify the page content, many extensions do this.

Or I believe that a Greasemonkey script could do the same thing as well, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/